# How to add product name and logo?

Tags: javadoc, doclet

In the [JDK javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), on the left panel above all-classes, there is a product name like:

```
Java™ Platform
Standard Ed. 7
```

It is also in the header and footer of every page.

1. How to add product name in javadoc in every page?
2. How to add logo in page header or footer in every page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [javadoc tool page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) you can configure that sort of stuff in a variety of ways, including CSS, frame files and a base `index.html`. Check out the sections "Support Pages" and "HTML Frames".

The easiest solution seems to be in the "Options" section, which is to use an appropriate combination of the `-top`, `-bottom`, `-header` and `-footer` options of the `javadoc` tool.

The example they give in there is pretty simple:

```
javadoc -header "<b>Java Platform </b><br>v1.4" com.mypackage.
```